# Cross validation returning 0 for train-merror and test-merror

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, xgboost, xgbclassifier

Here is a sample from my data:

```
data

##        q6     q7 q8 q9 q10 q11 q12 q13 q14 q15 q16 q17 q18 q19 q20 q21 q22 q23  w
## 1    1.73  54.43  2  5   5   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3   2   2   2   2   2  0
## 2    1.50  51.26  2  5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1  0
## 3    1.90  66.68  1  5   1   1   1   1   1   1   3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA   1  NA  0
## 4      NA     NA  2  5   1   2   4   4   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   1  0
## 5    1.63  68.49  1  4   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   4   5  1
## 6    1.70  59.88  2  5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2  0
## 7    1.73  70.76  2  5   1   2   8   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2  1
## 8    1.75  90.72 NA  5   1  NA  NA   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   2   2  0 
## 9    1.50  40.82  2  4   2   1   1   3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3   2  0
## 10   1.68  49.90  1  5   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2  0
## 11   1.50  86.18  1  3   2  NA   6   4   1   1   2   8   5   1   1   1  NA  NA  1 
## 12   1.88  79.83  3  5   1   2   2   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   2   1   1  1
## 13   1.78  68.49  2  4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2  1
## 14   1.73  54.43  2  4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   2   2   2  0
## 15   1.80  72.58  2  4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3   1   1   2   2   2  0
```

Then I cross validated this data:

```
xgb.cv(data=as.matrix(data),label=data$w, num_class=2, nrounds=20, nfold=5, eval_metric="merror", lambda=1, objective = "multi:softmax")
```

My label is the "w" column. The num_class is 2 as "w" has either 0 or 1 class. My final goal is build a classifier to predict labels w from data with xgboost however when I ran the above xgb.cv it returns me this:

```
## [1]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [2]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [3]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [4]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [5]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [6]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [7]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [8]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [9]  train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [10] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [11] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [12] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [13] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [14] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [15] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [16] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [17] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [18] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [19] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000 
## [20] train-merror:0.000000+0.000000  test-merror:0.000000+0.000000
```

All train and test merror are 0. Why? How do I solve this?

Here is the requested `dput(head(data))`:

```
## structure(list(q6 = c(1.73, 1.5, 1.9, NA, 1.63, 1.7), q7 = c(54.43, 
## 51.26, 66.68, NA, 68.49, 59.88), q8 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2), q9 = c(5, 
## 5, 5, 5, 4, 5), q10 = c(5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1), q11 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 
## 1, 1), q12 = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1), q13 = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1), 
##     q14 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), q15 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), q16 = c(1, 
##     1, 3, 1, 1, 1), q17 = c(2, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1), q18 = c(3, 1, 
##     NA, 2, 1, 1), q19 = c(2, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1), q20 = c(2, 1, NA, 
##     2, 1, 1), q21 = c(2, 2, NA, 2, 1, 2), q22 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 
##     4, 2), q23 = c(2, 1, NA, 1, 5, 2), q24 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
##     1), q25 = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1), q26 = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
##     q27 = c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), q28 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1), q29 = c(1, 
##     1, NA, 1, 1, 3), q30 = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 3), q31 = c(1, 2, 
##     NA, 1, 1, 1), q32 = c(6, 1, NA, 6, 6, 1), q33 = c(NA, 1, 
##     NA, 2, 5, 1), q34 = c(NA, 1, NA, 2, 4, 1), q35 = c(NA, 1, 
##     NA, 5, 5, 1), q36 = c(2, 1, NA, 3, 3, 1), q37 = c(1, 1, NA, 
##     1, 1, 1), q38 = c(6, 1, NA, 4, 1, 1), q39 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 
##     1, 2), q40 = c(3, 1, NA, 2, 7, 1), q41 = c(6, 1, 2, 5, 6, 
##     3), q42 = c(5, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6), q43 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2), 
##     q44 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, NA), q45 = c(1, 1, 1, 5, 7, 4), q46 = c(1, 
##     1, 1, 6, 5, 7), q47 = c(7, 1, NA, 7, 7, 6), q48 = c(6, 1, 
##     7, 5, 5, 6), q49 = c(4, 1, NA, 6, 1, 4), q50 = c(1, 1, 1, 
##     2, 3, 1), q51 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), q52 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
##     1, 1), q53 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1), q54 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
##     1), q55 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1), q56 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
##     q57 = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2), q58 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), q59 = c(1, 
##     2, 2, 2, 1, 1), q60 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1), q61 = c(7, 1, 
##     2, 5, 6, 6), q62 = c(3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5), q63 = c(3, 1, 3, 
##     2, 4, 5), q64 = c(3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2), q65 = c(2, 1, 2, 2, 
##     2, 3), q66 = c(4, 1, NA, 4, 4, 2), q67 = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
##     2), q68 = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1), q69 = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3), 
##     q70 = c(2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 1), q71 = c(3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2), q72 = c(4, 
##     4, 4, 2, 3, 2), q73 = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), q74 = c(2, 2, 
##     3, 2, 2, 2), q75 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1), q76 = c(7, 2, 2, 
##     2, 2, 1), q77 = c(3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 7), q78 = c(1, 2, 4, 2, 
##     1, 3), q79 = c(4, 8, 6, 3, 1, 2), q80 = c(6, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
##     4), q81 = c(5, NA, 1, 4, 2, 1), q82 = c(7, 1, 6, 5, 2, 7), 
##     q83 = c(1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6), q84 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), q85 = c(2, 
##     2, 1, 2, 2, 2), q86 = c(1, 1, NA, 1, 1, 1), q87 = c(2, 2, 
##     NA, 2, 2, 1), q88 = c(4, 5, 5, 3, 1, 2), q89 = c(4, 2, 2, 
##     4, 2, 4), q90 = c(2, 1, NA, NA, 1, 2), q91 = c(1, 1, 1, 3, 
##     3, 1), q92 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 5), q93 = c(4, 5, 7, 4, 7, 
##     2), q94 = c(3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2), q95 = c(1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4), 
##     q96 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), q97 = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3), q98 = c(1, 
##     2, 2, 1, 1, 1), q99 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), w = c(0, 0, 0, 
##     0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The objective is incorrecly specified try binary:logistic

Comment: use head(df) |> dput()

Comment: @Bruno I just tried head(df) |> dput() but it is giving error when printing

Comment: @Bruno I did head(dput(df)) instead but it still returns way too much for me to edit.

Comment: try removing some of the features

Comment: @Bruno I tried your method changing the objective to binary:logistic but it returns me error: Check failed: preds.size() == info.labels_Size() (24424 vs. 12212) : labels are not correctly providedpreds.size=24424, label.size=12212, Loss binary:logistic

Comment: @Bruno How do I remove some of the features?

Comment: just drop some columns

Comment: @Bruno I have dropped all the columns except 2 columns. Yet head(dput()) still gives me a huge chunk

Comment: @Bruno The question doesn't let me post. The limit for stackoverflow is 30000 characters, mine is 140k with only 2 columns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238374/discussion-between-jeseeling-and-bruno).

Comment: How about `dput(head(df))` instead of `head(dput(df))`?

Comment: @MartinGal Thanks I have updated the question with my dput(head(data)). Could you have a look now please?

Comment: @Skaqqs I have updated my question with dput(head(data)), could you have a look at it again please? Thanks

Comment: Try using the default evaluation metric `xgb.cv(data=as.matrix(df), label=df$w, num_class=2, nrounds=20, nfold=5, lambda=1, objective="multi:softmax")`

Comment: @Skaqqs Hi thanks it is now printing but is there a way I could change the objective into binary:logistic instead?

Comment: Sure, just remove `num_class=` argument e.g., `xgb.cv(data=as.matrix(df), label=df$w, nrounds=20, nfold=5, lambda=1, objective="binary:logistic")`

Comment: @Skaqqs Hey man that gives me error: label must be in [0, num_class), num_class=1 but found 1 in label

Comment: I just double checked, and it works on my machine with your example data. Is your data called `df`? Did you try the code from my previous comment exactly?

Comment: @Skaqqs xgb.cv(data=as.matrix(new), label=new$w, nrounds=20, nfold=5, lambda=1, objective="binary:logistic", eval_metric="merror")

Comment: this is my exact code and new is my data

Comment: Yeah, apparently there's an issue using `merror` with your data. Using the default eval metric avoids that issue.

Comment: @Skaqqs Ok I changed "merror" to "error" but now it is showing all 0 again for train and test-error?

Comment: Same code as above. Use this exactly: `xgb.cv(data=as.matrix(df), label=df$w, nrounds=20, nfold=5, lambda=1, objective="binary:logistic")`

Comment: @Skaqqs yea but why? Doesn't it have any error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238377/discussion-between-skaqqs-and-jeseeling).